# Selecting polygon features that have centers outside of another polygon feature class using ArcMap/ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, polygon

Since I only have Incorporated area feature class, how can I select census blocks that are in unincorporated area? Or not within any incorporated areas using ArcMap or ArcPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select by Location, in Arcinfo, will give you a variety of options to refine that requirement.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it in ArcGIS 10 with ArcView level license? Thank you.

Comment: I believe that Select By Locatino is available in all licences of Arc.  Have a look here for more details: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000tp000000.  You can select all the ones that DO have their centers in an unincorporated area and then for the second part of your question, just switch selection.

Comment: I did use select by location with "HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN" in Python. But I could not find a switch selection option after that. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Open the attribute table of the feature class/layer with the selected features and click (should be) fourth button from the left to switch the selection. The selection modification options are generally found within the attribute table.

Comment: Thanks, AHigh. What I want to do is to use Python to select all polygons from one polygon feature class that do not have their centers within another polygon feature class. This needs to be completed within Python. Thanks.

Comment: If you're doing it in Python simply add a line under your SelectLayerByLocation() that goes something like this: SelectLayerByAttribute("LayerWithSelections","SWITCH_SELECTION") http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Select_Layer_By_Attribute/001700000071000000/

Comment: SelectLayerByAttribute("LayerWithSelections","SWITCH_SELECTION") worked!

Answer (score 8):

Give this a shot:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:\\yourWorkspace"
arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer("incorporatedPlaces","incorporatedPlacesLyr")
arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer("censusBlocks","censusBlockLyr")

arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation("censusBlockLyr","HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN","incorporatedPlacesLyr")
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttributes("censusBlockLyr","SWITCH_SELECTION")
```

To read more about this check out this link from ESRI Help: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Select_Layer_By_Attribute/001700000071000000/